# Hazelcast : Portal serialization, Incompatible class-definitions with same class-id, version- 3.11.4

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to store a map object in Hazelcast cache, map object inturn contains a key and an object, when I try to store map object into hazel cast cache, I'm getting below error, am I missing anything here? Thanks in advance.

Caused by:

> com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Incompatible class-definitions with same class-id:
> ClassDefinition{factoryId=2, classId=127, version=6118, fieldDefinitions=
> [FieldDefinitionImpl{index=0, fieldName='fieldOne', type=PORTABLE_ARRAY, classId=130, factoryId=2, version=6118},
> FieldDefinitionImpl{index=1, fieldName='fieldTwo', type=UTF, classId=0, factoryId=0, version=6118},
> FieldDefinitionImpl{index=2, fieldName='fieldThree', type=UTF, classId=0, factoryId=0, version=6118},
> FieldDefinitionImpl{index=3, fieldName='fieldFour', type=UTF, classId=0, factoryId=0, version=6118},
> FieldDefinitionImpl{index=4, fieldName='fieldFive', type=PORTABLE, classId=128, factoryId=2, version=6118},
> FieldDefinitionImpl{index=5, fieldName='fieldSix', type=LONG, classId=0, factoryId=0, version=6118}]}

VS

> ClassDefinition{factoryId=2, classId=127, version=6118,
> fieldDefinitions=[
> FieldDefinitionImpl{index=0, fieldName='fieldOne', type=PORTABLE_ARRAY, classId=130, factoryIdxajo=2, version=6118},
> FieldDefinitionImpl{index=1, fieldName='fieldTwo', type=UTF, classId=0, factoryId=0, version=6118},
> FieldDefinitionImpl{index=2, fieldName='fieldThree', type=UTF, classId=0, factoryId=0, version=6118},
> FieldDefinitionImpl{index=3, fieldName='fieldFour', type=UTF, classId=0, factoryId=0, version=6118},
> FieldDefinitionImpl{index=4, fieldName='fieldFive', type=PORTABLE, classId=123, factoryId=2, version=6118},
> FieldDefinitionImpl{index=5, fieldName='fieldSix', type=PORTABLE, classId=128, factoryId=2, version=6118},
> FieldDefinitionImpl{index=6, fieldName='fieldSeven', type=LONG, classId=0, factoryId=0, version=6118}]}

I see that one of the field is missing, but I'm populating all fields under write Portable method. There is only one class definition created for class Id 127

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using different attribute names. Compare the two messages you have posted above and look for the following:

{factoryId=2, classId=127, version=6118, fieldDefinitions=[ FieldDefinitionImpl{index=0, fieldName='fieldOne', type=PORTABLE_ARRAY, classId=130, **factoryIdxajo=2**, version=6118},

Answer (score 0):

A common issue (bug) I see is the readPortable and writePortable are using different field names. Can you post your Portable implementation?

A current beta feature that should be GA in the next release is Generic Records when using Portable serialization, might be of interest:

https://hazelcast.com/blog/hazelcast-imdg-4-1-ga-is-released/

https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.1/manual/html-single/index.html#accessing-domain-objects-without-domain-classes